# How does Maddening Hex behave in 1 vs 1?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Maddening Hex](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Maddening%20Hex) contains the following action:

> Then attach Maddening Hex to **another** one of your opponents chosen at random.

When there's only one opponent, what happens to Maddening Hex?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Maddening Hex stays attached to your opponent.**

Since you don't have another opponent, the instruction is impossible and it simply won't be executed.

> 101.3. Any part of an instruction that’s impossible to perform is ignored. (In many cases the card will specify consequences for this; if it doesn’t, there’s no effect.)